# calculate the 7 day sale by different start date (the first day customer purchase), to find average purchase unit of each customer by every 7 days

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

From the table，I have the first table now, and trying to get every 7 day sales from the first day of this customer make the purchase. example is table 2

| purchase date | customer id | sales unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | 10 |
| 2018-01-02 | 1 | 5 |
| 2018-01-05 | 2 | 3 |
| 2018-01-15 | 1 | 10 |
| 2018-01-20 | 2 | 4 |
| 2018-01-21 | 2 | 5 |

| purchase date | customer id | sales unit | every 7 day cumulative sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2018-01-02 | 1 | 5 | 15 |
| 2018-01-15 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2018-01-05 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2018-01-20 | 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 2018-01-21 | 2 | 5 | 9 |

The final table shud be like this:

| purchase week | customer id | 7 day sales unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | 15 |
| 2018-01-05 | 2 | 3 |
| 2018-01-15 | 1 | 10 |
| 2018-01-20 | 2 | 4 |

then I can calculate the average sales per customer

| customer id | average of every 7 day sales unit | Calculation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.5 | (15+10) /2 |
| 2 | 3.5 | (3+4) /2 |

the hard part is:

1. every customer have different first day of purchase
2. The purchase date are not consequent, so I can't use unbonded or following 6 rows etc.
3. There're 5 years in the whole dataset, so I can't manually -7, -14, etc
4. I tried to use date_trunc('week',date, min(date) over (partition by customerid))
5. also tried parition by rows between 6 proceding and current row. But the date are not consequent so doesn't work

Comment: Can you upgrade to Trino or you are required to use Presto ATM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL window function with 2 steps to get the result you want:

Step 1. Apply a window parition by per customer and get first_purchase_date for each customer. After that, use Presto [date_diff()](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#interval-functions) fucntion to calculate the date difference from first purchase date to current purchase date. Devide it by 7 to get week_bucket from the first date of purchase.

Step 2. group by per (customer, customer_sale_week_bucket) and get sum(sales_unit) and min(purchase_date) in each (customer, customer_sale_week_bucket) parition.

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cce2ec/5):

```
with orders_with_customer_week_bucket AS 
(
  select
   purchase_date,
   customer_id,
   sales_unit,
   date_diff(day,min(purchase_date) over (partition by customer_id), purchase_date) / 7 as customer_sale_week_bucket
from
   orders
 )
 select
     purchase_week,
     customer_id,
     seven_day_sales_unit
 from
     (select
         customer_id,
         customer_sale_week_bucket,
         min(purchase_date) as purchase_week,
         sum(sales_unit) as seven_day_sales_unit
     from
        orders_with_customer_week_bucket
     GROUP BY
        customer_id,
        customer_sale_week_bucket
     )r
```

| purchase_week | customer_id | seven_day_sales_unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | 15 |
| 2018-01-05 | 2 | 3 |
| 2018-01-15 | 1 | 10 |
| 2018-01-20 | 2 | 9 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a case statement looking at the dates. I did this in SQL Server but I believe it works in Presto. I think DATEADD might need to be "Date_Add" (with the quotes) in Presto.

Also you mentioned you may need 14 days so I added a column for that. You can see it's just a matter of changing the days in the DateAdd function.

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/fUFArnRQ)

```
   SELECT t1.purchaseDate,
          t1.CustomerID,
          t1.SalesUnit,
          SUM(CASE 
                 WHEN t2.purchaseDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -6, t1.purchaseDate) AND t1.purchaseDate THEN t2.salesUnit 
               END) AS SalesLast7,
          SUM(CASE 
                 WHEN t2.purchaseDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -13, t1.purchaseDate) AND t1.purchaseDate THEN t2.salesUnit 
               END) AS SalesLast14  
     FROM temp t1
LEFT JOIN temp t2 ON t1.customerID = t2.customerID AND t2.purchaseDate IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY t1.purchaseDate, t1.customerID, t1.salesUnit
```

| purchaseDate | CustomerID | SalesUnit | SalesLast7 | SalesLast14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2018-01-02 | 1 | 5 | 15 | 15 |
| 2018-01-05 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 2018-01-15 | 1 | 10 | 10 | 15 |
| 2018-01-20 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 4 |

Comment: No sure about that date check in the join. Shouldn't you just limit to dates in the largest window?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember why I added that. I assume I put it in there for something but at this point it doesn't actually do anything. Removing it doesn't change the results based on the sample data..

Comment: Hi @TomBoyd thank you and it works! But I'm struggling with the final step which is how to find the average. But this is super helpful!

Comment: To do that, I need you to define what a week is. I believe you were wanting a rolling 7 day period based on the date of the first transaction partitioned by customer. If so, how many customers do you have? If it's a lot, this could get extremely resource intensive to calculate and maintain. If instead you're willing to use the ISO standard week, this becomes much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your sample data is tallied right. It's not clear to me if you truly need the cumulative values per week or just a straight total. My guess is that you want something in one of these two options.

```
with salesweek as (
    select *,
        -- weeks based on repeating 7-day counter starting at first purchase
        date_diff('day',
            min(purchasedate) over (partition by customerid),
            purchasedate) / 7 + 1 as weeknum -- integer divide
    from T
)
select customerid, sum(salesunit) * 1.0 / count(distinct weeknum) as avg7daysales
from salesweek
group by customerid;
```

Or possibly:

```
with firstpurchase as (
    select *,
        min(purchasedate) over (partition by customerid) as firstpurchasedate
    from T
  ), salesweek as (
    select *,
        -- weeks based on repeating 7-day counter starting at first purchase
        date_diff('day', firstpurchasedate, purchasedate) / 7 + 1 as weeknum
    from firstpurchase
  ), weighted as (
    select customerid, weeknum, purchasedate,
        sum(salesunit) * count(1) over (
            partition by customerid, weeknum
            order by purchasedate
            rows between current row and unbounded following
        ) as weightedsales
    from salesweek
    group by customerid, weeknum, purchasedate
)
select customerid, sum(weightedsales) * 1.0 / count(distinct weeknum)
from weighted
group by customerid
order by customerid;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/sgOOd07H

This is in SQL Server since I don't have access to Presto.